# Vagrant freezes on SSH connection when HyperV is ON

Tags: docker, vagrant, virtualbox, hyper-v

This is my configuration:

- Windows 10 PRO (with HyperV ON)
- Vagrant (2.2.13)
- VirtualBox (6.1.16)

I read that upper configuration should works without switching "hypervisorlaunchtype" but something is wrong:

```
λ vagrant up                                                                       
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...                        
==> default: Checking if box 'sternpunkt/jimmybox' version '3.0.2' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...                        
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...                     
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...                
    default: Adapter 1: nat                                                        
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly                                                   
==> default: Forwarding ports...                                                   
    default: 80 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)                                 
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)                                 
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...                               
==> default: Booting VM...                                                         
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...           
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222                                           
    default: SSH username: vagrant                                                 
    default: SSH auth method: private key                                          
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that                   
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within                    
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.                       
                                                                                   
If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that                     
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors                
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.                                    
                                                                                   
If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly                
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common                  
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.                       
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,                 
as well.                                                                           
                                                                                   
If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase                
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Vagrant, VB and Windows are the newest version. Vagrant runs right when hypervisorlaunchtype is off. I have to temporarily use Vagrant and Docker simultaninuosly.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my issue:

```
v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cableconnected1", "on"]
```

Just added it to vagrantfile.

[Edit]
Sometimes it runs quick, sometimes running takes a couple minutes, but sometimes it doesn't run and returns timeout warning.